# must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'lessThan (...)', e.g. '(... ->* lessThan) (...)'

Tags: c++, qt, qsort, qlist

I am trying to sort my QList based on a QDateTime but I get the following error:

```
must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'lessThan (...)', e.g. '(... ->* lessThan) (...)'
 if (lessThan(*end, *start))
                          ^
```

Sort function:

```
bool sortRecord(Record left, Record right){
    return left.getArrival().getDate() < right.getArrival().getDate();
}
```

Function is called like this:

```
qSort(recordList.begin(), recordList.end(), sortRecord);
```

Getter and setter of arrival in Record:

```
void Record::setArrival(Arrival arrival){
    this->arrival = arrival;
}
Arrival Record::getArrival(){
    return this->arrival;
}
```

`getDate()` function in Arrival:

```
QDateTime Arrival::getDate(){
    QDateTime qDateTime;

    QDate qDate;
    qDate.setDate(date.getDateYear(), date.getDateMonth(), date.getDateDay());
    qDateTime.setDate(qDate);

    vector<string> timeS = splitTime(time.getTimeFrom());

    QTime qTime;
    qTime.setHMS(stoi(timeS[0]), stoi(timeS[1]), 0);
    qDateTime.setTime(qTime);

    return qDateTime;
}
```

What is it that I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `lessThan` used, where is it declared?

Comment: The function lessThan is declared inside the qalgorithms.h that is part of the QT framework.

Comment: So where/how do you invoke the sort?

Comment: My guess is that `sortRecord` is a non-static member function, which you're passing to Qt's sorting function. Make it static, or liberate it entirely from the shackles of the class system.

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary off-site links. Questions such as this one should be self-contained. The entirety of your problem can be illustrated in about 10 lines of self-contained `main.cpp` - that's what should have been in your question to begin with. Your job is to throw out everything that doesn't contribute to the problem: it's just noise.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
qSort(recordList.begin(), recordList.end(), sortRecord);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You cannot use a non-static member function as the sort function, because a non-static member function needs to be called on some object (to provide the `this` pointer). You can't just call  member function like a normal function, which is what  the compiler error means. If you'd read the whole error message, not just the first line, then it would have told you that it comes from the line above.

Either make the `sortRecord` function a non-member function, or make it a `static` member function.

Why is it a member function anyway? It doesn't access `*this`, or use any private members ... this smells like bad object oriented style, that's not how we do things in C++ (see e.g. [How non-member functions increase encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)).

Also why does your `sortRecord` function copy its arguments instead of using references? (See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#call-by-reference)

If you want to write everything as a member function and have pass-by-reference semantics then use Java, not C++. Otherwise, stop writing Java code in C++.

Comment: You might want to tone down. OP is clearly new to C++. You could've posted some suggestive feedback instead of flaming him for trying. We all were new to something once, even you, Einstein.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function for sorting.

```
bool sortRecord(const Record& left, const Record& right)
{ 
    return left.getArrival().getDate() < right.getArrival().getDate(); 
}
```

And also make sure that getArrival() and getDate() are const methods.

Comment: Although that is a good suggestion, it doesn't solve the problem.